# Syntax error for node.js

Tags: json, node.js, parsing

I am getting syntax error while parsing a json file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node


'use strict';
var pID = require('./pull.json')
```

This is the error:

```
 module.js:453
        throw err;
        ^

    SyntaxError: /data/slave/jsonParse/pull.json: Unexpected token {
        at Object.parse (native)
        at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:450:27)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
```

Comment: probably your json file is not valid. Try validating your json file and then try to parse it. The parser has thrown the error, since the json file is not valid

Comment: are you sure `pull.json` contains valid json?

Comment: can you give your json file

Comment: @a3.14_Infinity The json file was created using curl command via shell script.So it should be fine.

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon It should be valid

Comment: @Franklin what makes you say It should be valid? Error clearly says `unexpected token` which means there is something wrong with josn. Have you tested your json with my answer links or can you provide your `json` content so that we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `pull.json` does not contain valid `json`, you can try following links to validate it or find where is flaw:

[jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

[jsonformatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)